# Mount shares as regular user in Linux Mint 17.1?

Tags: linux, mount, network-shares, linux-mint, nemo

All the shares `fstab` tries to mount show up in the navigation panel in Nemo for me. If for whatever reason a share didn’t get mounted at startup, clicking on it tries to mount it for me. Except that it complains that I’m not root.

Is there a way to mount these at the user level so that they can be mounted/umounted without su?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing a sample of your `fstab`, not too clear how your system is setup. But I believe you can use the `user` option in the `fstab` entry something like this [as explained here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1513); empahsis is mine on the option relevant to your question:

> - **user**/nouser - **Permit any user to mount the filesystem.** (This automatically implies noexec, nosuid,nodev unless overridden) / Only
>     permit root to mount the filesystem. This is also a default setting.

Now you need to know what the `fstab` entry format is like; here is a simple breakdown:

```
/thing/to/be/mounted    /mount/point    file_system_type    options    dump    pass
```

Knowing that, the `user` option would be tagged onto the `options` list as another comma delimited item like this; and here is a theoretical `fstab` entry example for reference:

```
/dev/sdb1    /home/leetwanker/mount_point    ext3    defaults,noatime,user    0    0
```

So in this example, the file system on `/dev/sdb1` will be mounted on the mount point known as `/home/leetwanker/mount_point` which has an `ext3` file format and has the options `defaults,noatime,user` as well as dump and pass values of `0`.

With the `user` option in place in the `fstab`, reboot your system and you can then use `mount` and `umount` without any `sudo` restriction prompts or requirements.